# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I know this is common question, but I keep getting this error when fetching data:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse ()

This happened when I testing my full code, so I made tested with

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({"data": "test"}));
```

In my client side, I'm using this code:

```
fetch(url)                                   // fetch works
    .then(checkStatus)                       // checks for errors, if none send response text
    .then(function (responseText) {
        let data = JSON.parse(responseText); // where I'm getting the error
```

When testing the values, everything in my server side prints the correct values. However, when I use console.log to print out the responseText on the client side, I get this:

> f text() { [native code] }

Why is this error being called? From looking around stack overflow, I understand that this error happens when I attempt to parse a string that's undefined. I put an if statement before the parse to check is the string is undefined:

```
if (responseText === undefined) {
    console.log("responseText is undefined");
}
```

But it didn't output, so is the string really undefined? As a side note, node is up to date. Thank you for helping.If this is answered in another question, please let me know. I haven't found a solution to this problem.

Edit:

```
function checkStatus(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.text;
    } else if (response.status === 404) {
        clear();
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Sorry, we couldn't find that page"));
    } else {
        console.log(response.text());
        return Promise.reject(new Error(response.status + ": " + response.statusText));
    }
}
```

Edit: response.text is supposed to be response.text(). This gave me my error.

Comment: What **exactly** is `checkStatus` doing?

Comment: I think your problem is `checkStatus` function. It returns string start with `'u'`, please `console.log(responseText)` and show `checkStatus`.

Comment: I added the checkStatus function to the question

Comment: @GrimThor3 thanks, that's much clearer. I've updated my answer below

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated to match new question code

A promise chain resolves each new promise with the return value from the last.

You should note the `fetch()` API returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) resolving with a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. This does not have a `text` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Properties), so `checkStatus` is resolving with `undefined` (hence the "u" in the error message).

I suggest you use the [`Body.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method to parse the JSON response, ie change `checkStatus` to use

```js
if (res.ok) { // same as checking status between [200, 300)
  return res.json()
}
if (res.status === 404) {
  clear()
  return Promise.reject(new Error("Sorry, we couldn't find that page"))
}
// text(), like json() returns a promise
return res.text().then(responseText => {
  console.error(responseText)
  return Promise.reject(new Error(`${res.status}: ${res.statusText}`))
})
```

and for `fetch()`...

```js
fetch(url)
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(data => {
    // data is already parsed into an object
  })
```

---

On the server-side, you might want to use [`res.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) instead of manually stringifying your data

```js
res.json({ data: 'test' })
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the culprit

Comment: Thanks. I'll implement this and try to understand Body.json()